# How to pass multiple parameters for aiohttp request wit the same name?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, aiohttp

The API from which I want to receive data takes several values with the same name as a parameter:

```
https://example.com/method?types=Retail&types=Office&types=Industrial......
```

I try to do it like this:

```py
params_api_sale = {
    'types': [
        'Retail', 'Office', 'Industrial', 
        'Mixed Use', 'Development Site', 
        'Land', 'Special Purpose', 'Other'
    ],
    'sortDirection': 'Descending',
    'sortOrder': 'ActivatedOn'
}

async def get_items():
    async with aiohttp.request(
        method='GET', url=vars_.url_api_sale, 
        headers=vars_.headers, params=vars_.params_api_sale) as response:
        ...
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 85, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "foo.py", line 80, in main
    await asyncio.create_task(get_items())
  File "foo.py", line 44, in get_items
    headers=vars_.headers, params=vars_.params_api_sale) as response:
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1051, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 473, in _request
    ssl=ssl, proxy_headers=proxy_headers, traces=traces)
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 263, in __init__
    url2 = url.with_query(params)
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\yarl\__init__.py", line 922, in with_query
    new_query = self._get_str_query(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\yarl\__init__.py", line 886, in _get_str_query
    quoter(k) + "=" + quoter(self._query_var(v)) for k, v in query.items()
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\yarl\__init__.py", line 886, in <genexpr>
    quoter(k) + "=" + quoter(self._query_var(v)) for k, v in query.items()
  File "D:\Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\yarl\__init__.py", line 864, in _query_var
    "of type {}".format(v, type(v))
TypeError: Invalid variable type: value should be str or int, got ['Retail', 'Office', 'Industrial', 'Mixed Use', 'Development Site', 'Land', 'Special Purpose', 'Other'] of type <class 'list'>
```

I have not found a documented way to do this. All that comes to my mind is to generate a URL string with these parameters, of course, if there is no more correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import requests

params = {
    'types': [
        'Retail', 'Office', 'Industrial',
        'Mixed Use', 'Development Site',
        'Land', 'Special Purpose', 'Other'
    ],
    'sortDirection': 'Descending',
    'sortOrder': 'ActivatedOn'
}

r = requests.get("http://www.test.com/", params=params)

print(r.url)
```

output:

```
https://www.test.com/?types=Retail&types=Office&types=Industrial&types=Mixed+Use&types=Development+Site&types=Land&types=Special+Purpose&types=Other&sortDirection=Descending&sortOrder=ActivatedOn
```

For `aiohttp` you can use `MultiDict` which is also included in the official document.

> For sending data with multiple values for the same key MultiDict may be used as well.

Answer (score 4):

As stated at [aiohttp documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v0.13.1/client.html#passing-parameters-in-urls), you can pass a list of tuples to `params` with the same key to achieve your goal:

> Also it is possible to pass list of 2 items tuples as parameters, in that case you can specifiy multiple values for each key:

```
params = [
    ("key1", "value1"),
    ("key1", "value2"),
    ("key2", "value3"),
]
```